# Complex Hibernate Queries

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

Im wondering if its possible to implement the following type of functionality in a Java Spring/Hibernate application.   A user might have, in addition to first, last name, email, etc. a profile, the contents of which consist of a paragraph.  Would it be possible to write a query such that users could be grouped based a certain matching keywords or phrases?  The only way I can think to accomplish this would be too loop through the entire database and perform comparisons.  This would be exceeding slow and would also defeat the whole purpose of a database.

Any suggestions pointing me in the right way much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: you want to get list of users that matches some keyword or get multiple list of users grouped by a predefined keywords list?

Comment: I want to have users.  Users will have about a half page profile. I want to be able to match users with similar profiles by scanning for particular keywords.  The keywords/phrases will be predefined.

Comment: Supposing that your JPA entity called User and it has the following properties: firstName, lastName, email, and profile; (probably this will be non-unique indexed field); then your query is something like:

    `select a
    from User a 
    group by a.firstName, a.lastName, a.email, a.profile
 having a.profile like '%Some_Keyword1%' or a.profile like '%Some_Keyword2%' or a.profile like '%Some_Keyword3%'`
 
this will return a list of users then you can filer to a sub list like:
userList.stream().filter(a -> a.contains("Some_Keyword1")).collect(Collectors.toList());